# Splitting string only at the first matching regex position

Tags: java, regex

I have this string:
"123456 - A, Bcd, 789101 - E, Fgh"

I want it split into: "123456 - A, Bcd" and "789101 - E, Fgh".
How can I achieve this? What `regex` and `split` expressions should I use?

I see I can find the comma after "Bcd" using `.matches(".*[a-z],\\s[0-9].*")`
but how do I split the strings ONLY at that comma? `.split(",\\s")` splits at all occurring comma followed by space...

I work with JAVA 1.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may split on the comma that is followed with 0+ whitespaces, 6 digits, space and a hyphen:

```
String[] result = s.split(",\\s*(?=\\d{6} -)");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s3hs0S/2/).

**Pattern details**

- `,` - a comma
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `(?=\\d{6} -)` - a positive lookahead (a non-consuming pattern, what it matches won't be part of the result) that requires 6 digits followed with a space and `-` immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Cool! Thanks. (Y)